# D3: Preserve minutes in time scale interval

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to have time intervals with exact minutes in the x axis ticks. I am creating a time scale as following:

```
const x = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date(), new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)])
      .nice()
      .range([this.config.containerOffset.left, this.dimensions.svg.width - this.config.containerOffset.right]);
```

then I create an interval and pass it to the ticks

```
const interval = d3.timeHour.every(3);

...
  .ticks(interval)
  .tickFormat((d) => format(d, 'HH:mm:ss')),
...
```

but the interval resets minutes and rounds time down to hours and then counts the specified interval so I get:

```
12:00:00  15:00:00  18:00:00  21:00:00 ...
```

How can I make so that the interval also preserves minutes in the ticks, so if my start time is 12:28 then the ticks show

```
12:28:00  15:28:00  18:28:00  21:28:00 ...
```

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Here is a codepen with working code showing my issue with ticks values:
https://codepen.io/m0t0r/pen/dyPgRGy?editors=1010

Comment: can you add a workding jsfiddle so that it is easy to look into it?

Comment: have tried removing nice() ?

Comment: Added a codepen. @UmeshMaharshi, yes I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a potential solution for your problem on a post by Neha Gupta [here](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/adjust-time-scale-representation-on-x-axis/#) but I'm posting it here because the link may break in the future.

The post outlines a function that generates 'custom' ticks. The function takes three arguments; the start and end dates [of the domain], and a step argument.

```
function customTickFunc (t0, t1, step)
{
    var startTime = new Date(t0),
    endTime= new Date(t1), times = [];
    endTime.setUTCDate(endTime.getUTCDate() + 1);
    while (startTime < endTime) {
       startTime.setUTCDate(startTime.getUTCDate() + 2);
       times.push(new Date(startTime));
     }
    return times;
}
```

When you implement the function :

```
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(customTickFunc);
```

... this will override the default 'rounding'/automatic tick behaviour and generate the required ticks. A sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/315v9d07/3/) is provided on the page. It's rather hard to see (at least on my screen) but the timescale on the jsfiddle goes 4:03  6:03  8:03 etc.. similar to what you want

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I am using D3 v5.x and the code you posted is for D3 v3.x. The ticks function seems no longer has those arguments.